# Can I new a dynamic array in a program?

Tags: system-verilog

```
program test();
logic [7:0] a[];
a = new[10];
endprogram
```

I try to `new` a dynamic array in a `program`, and I compiled it with VCS, but it failed.

The error shows that：

> Following verilog source has syntax error : "test1.sv", 20: token is
> '='
> a = new[10];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = new[10];
```

This is a procedual statement, so it should be put within some kind of procedual block, e.g. `initial` block:

```
program test();
    logic [7:0] a[];
    initial begin
        a = new[10];
    end
endprogram
```

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with program blocks, which [I suggest you avoid anyways](https://blogs.sw.siemens.com/verificationhorizons/2009/05/07/programblocks/).

You *can* `new` a dynamic array, but the constructor needs to be either in procedural code, or part of a variable declaration initialization.

```
module test;
  logic [7:0] a[];
  initial begin
    a = new[10];
  end
  function automatic f;
    logic p7:0] b = new[10];
    b[2] = 3;
  endfunction
endmodule
```